# SciPy optimization doesn't return optimal solution

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm attempting to maximize a sectional area function related to my master thesis. I've come up with a function `double_T_Ixx`, and I wish to optimize it using SciPy's `minimize` function. While I understand the analytical solution, the optimization output is not aligning with my expectations.

Without too much background, I came up with this function:

```py
def double_T_Ixx(lengths, thicknesses):
    A_top_l = lengths[0] * thicknesses[0]
    A_top_r = lengths[1] * thicknesses[1]
    A_mid   = lengths[2] * thicknesses[2]
    A_bot_l = lengths[3] * thicknesses[3]
    A_bot_r = lengths[4] * thicknesses[4]

    y_top = lengths[2]
    y_mid = lengths[2] / 2
    y_bot = 0

    Ixx_top_l = (lengths[0] * thicknesses[0]**3) / 12
    Ixx_top_r = (lengths[1] * thicknesses[1]**3) / 12
    Ixx_mid   = (thicknesses[2] * lengths[2]**3) / 12
    Ixx_bot_l = (lengths[3] * thicknesses[3]**3) / 12
    Ixx_bot_r = (lengths[4] * thicknesses[4]**3) / 12

    A_total = A_top_l + A_top_r + A_mid + A_bot_l + A_bot_r
    y_composite = (A_top_l*y_top + A_top_r*y_top + A_mid*y_mid + A_bot_l*y_bot + A_bot_r*y_bot) / A_total

    Ixx = (Ixx_top_l + 
           Ixx_top_r + 
           Ixx_mid + 
           Ixx_bot_l + 
           Ixx_bot_r +
           A_top_l*(y_top - y_composite)**2 +
           A_top_r*(y_top - y_composite)**2 +
           A_mid  *(y_mid - y_composite)**2 +
           A_bot_l*(y_bot - y_composite)**2 +
           A_bot_r*(y_bot - y_composite)**2)
    return Ixx
```

wrapping this up into an objective and constraints yields:

```py
MIN_LENGTHS   = 1
MAX_LENGTH    = 10
MIN_THICKNESS = 0.5
MAX_THICKNESS = 2.5
MAX_AREA      = 10

def objective(x):
    num_segments = len(x) // 2
    lengths = x[:num_segments]
    thicknesses = x[num_segments:]
    
    return -double_T_Ixx(lengths, thicknesses)
    
def constraint_area(x):
    lengths = x[:len(x)//2]
    thicknesses = x[len(x)//2:]
    A_top_l = lengths[0] * thicknesses[0]
    A_top_r = lengths[1] * thicknesses[1]
    A_mid   = lengths[2] * thicknesses[2]
    A_bot_l = lengths[3] * thicknesses[3]
    A_bot_r = lengths[4] * thicknesses[4]
    return MAX_AREA - (A_top_l + A_top_r + A_mid + A_bot_l + A_bot_r)
```

## Expected Solution

From domain knowledge, I know there are multiple solutions. All of them have the same objective value, but they differ in parameter values. One representative solution is:

```
c = [l1 = 1, 
     l2 = 1, 
     l3 = 10, 
     l4 = 1, 
     l5 = 1,
 
     t1 = 1.25, 
     t2 = 1.25, 
     t3 = 0.5, 
     t4 = 1.25, 
     t5 = 1.25]
```

Generally l3 should be maximal while t3 should be minimal, l1, l2, l4, l5 should all be minimized, and t1, t2, t4, t5 should be maximized, given that we don't violate the area constraint.

## Attempt with SciPy's Minimize:

```py
constraints = [{'type':'eq', 'fun':lambda x: constraint_area(x)}]
initial_guess = [(b[0] + b[1] / 2) for b in bounds]

result = minimize(
    fun=objective,
    x0=initial_guess,
    method='SLSQP',
    bounds=bounds,
    constraints=constraints,
    tol=1e-12,
    options={'disp': True}
)
```

## Problem:

The solution I get from SciPy is close to the analytical solution in terms of the objective function, but not in terms of the actual values:

[2.265, 2.265, 10.000, 2.321, 2.270, 0.532, 0.567, 0.500, 0.562, 0.531]

However, as mentioned earlier, it would be optimal if l1, l2, l4, l5 equaled 1 while t1, t2, t4, t5 were maximized.

## Question:

How can I modify my optimization setup to achieve the expected optimal solution? Is my problem ill-posed for SciPy's optimizer, or am I missing something in its formulation or setup?

Comment: Can you add a diagram? If that's supposed to be an I-beam or similar then neither your centroid (y-composite) or use of the parallel-axis theorem to get Ixx are correct. Also, if there's left-right symmetry then you should reduce the number of parameters.

Comment: it is an I-Beam but what makes you think the centroid is incorrect? it assumes the thickness is negligible compared to the lengths so I am counting overlaps twice but I am neglecting that.

Comment: And I know that I could reduce the parameters to fully describe an I-Beam but that's not the point here. Without going into specifics, I am not going to assume symmetry

Comment: In calculating both centroid and second moment of area (Ixx) you need to work from the individual centrelines of the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right items, but you appear to be working from their edges (difficult to tell without a diagram). You can't have a negligible thickness and then include an area! It will make more of a difference than you think for Ixx: most of the resistance to bending comes from those parts, not from the web.

Comment: `However, as mentioned earlier, it would be optimal if l1, l2, l4, l5 equaled 1 while t1, t2, t4, t5 were maximized.` Plugging this into minimize and basinhopping, it finds a solution that scores better than the provided solution on the objective function: `[ 1. ,  1. , 10. ,  1. ,  1. ,  2. ,  0.5,  0.5,  2. ,  0.5]`. So is the question 1) about how to get the optimizer to optimize this function, or 2) how to change the objective function so that the solution you're looking for is optimal?

Comment: Can you provide complete, runnable, single-file code - then it would be possible to test your code properly. It is not possible to do so from several incomplete bits, as in your post at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "expected solution" is wrong.

For maximal second moment of area (Ixx - but, given your coordinate system, Iyy would be more sensible) you want as much material as possible as far away from the centre as possible. Thus you require the central element to have maximal length (10), and minimal width (0.5), whilst the side pieces should be as thin as possible (0.5) and as long as the total area would allow (2.5 on average, though you can displace material left to right if you don't require symmetry).

Here is such a solution. Note that I have corrected both your centroid and second-moment-of-area calculations to allow for finite thickness.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def double_T_Ixx(lengths, thicknesses):
    A_top_l = lengths[0] * thicknesses[0]
    A_top_r = lengths[1] * thicknesses[1]
    A_mid   = lengths[2] * thicknesses[2]
    A_bot_l = lengths[3] * thicknesses[3]
    A_bot_r = lengths[4] * thicknesses[4]

    y_top = lengths[2]
    y_mid = lengths[2] / 2
    y_bot = 0

    Ixx_top_l = lengths[0] * thicknesses[0] **3 / 12
    Ixx_top_r = lengths[1] * thicknesses[1] **3 / 12
    Ixx_mid   = thicknesses[2] * lengths[2] **3 / 12
    Ixx_bot_l = lengths[3] * thicknesses[3] **3 / 12
    Ixx_bot_r = lengths[4] * thicknesses[4] **3 / 12

    ytl = y_top - 0.5 * thicknesses[0]
    ytr = y_top - 0.5 * thicknesses[1]
    ybl = y_bot + 0.5 * thicknesses[3]
    ybr = y_bot + 0.5 * thicknesses[4]

    A_total = A_top_l + A_top_r + A_mid + A_bot_l + A_bot_r
#   y_composite = (A_top_l*y_top + A_top_r*y_top + A_mid*y_mid + A_bot_l*y_bot + A_bot_r*y_bot) / A_total
    y_composite = (    A_top_l * ytl
                     + A_top_r * ytr
                     + A_mid   * y_mid
                     + A_bot_l * ybl
                     + A_bot_r * ybr
                  ) / A_total

    Ixx = (Ixx_top_l + 
           Ixx_top_r + 
           Ixx_mid + 
           Ixx_bot_l + 
           Ixx_bot_r +
           A_top_l * ( ytl   - y_composite ) ** 2 +
           A_top_r * ( ytr   - y_composite ) ** 2 +
           A_mid   * ( y_mid - y_composite ) ** 2 +
           A_bot_l * ( ybl   - y_composite ) ** 2 +
           A_bot_r * ( ybr   - y_composite ) ** 2 )
    return Ixx


def objective(x):
    num_segments = len(x) // 2
    lengths = x[:num_segments]
    thicknesses = x[num_segments:]
    
    return -double_T_Ixx(lengths, thicknesses)
    

def constraint_area(x):
    lengths = x[:len(x)//2]
    thicknesses = x[len(x)//2:]
    A_top_l = lengths[0] * thicknesses[0]
    A_top_r = lengths[1] * thicknesses[1]
    A_mid   = lengths[2] * thicknesses[2]
    A_bot_l = lengths[3] * thicknesses[3]
    A_bot_r = lengths[4] * thicknesses[4]
    return MAX_AREA - (A_top_l + A_top_r + A_mid + A_bot_l + A_bot_r)


MIN_LENGTH    = 1
MAX_LENGTH    = 10.0
MIN_THICKNESS = 0.5
MAX_THICKNESS = 2.5
MAX_AREA      = 10.0
bounds = 5 * [ ( MIN_LENGTH, MAX_LENGTH ) ] + 5 * [ ( MIN_THICKNESS, MAX_THICKNESS ) ]

constraints = [ {'type':'eq', 'fun':lambda x: constraint_area(x)} ]

initial_guess = [ ( b[0] + b[1] ) / 2 for b in bounds ]

result = minimize(
    fun=objective,
    x0=initial_guess,
    method='SLSQP',
    bounds=bounds,
    constraints=constraints,
    tol=1e-12,
    options={'disp': True}
)

print( "Lengths = "    , result.x[0:5 ] )
print( "Thicknesses = ", result.x[5:10] )
```

Output:

```
Positive directional derivative for linesearch    (Exit mode 8)
            Current function value: -154.58333333407927
            Iterations: 82
            Function evaluations: 1431
            Gradient evaluations: 78
Lengths =  [ 2.50000471  2.4999953  10.          2.49999817  2.50000182]
Thicknesses =  [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5]
```

Comment: I accepted your answer yet I am very sure my computation of Ixx is correct under the assumption of thickness << lengths. Furthermore my expected solution is more or less what you described.